# confused about writing script for helloworld.js using node-windows in nodejs

Tags: node.js, windows-services, node-windows

I am using node-windows in nodejs to run my nodejs script as a windows service. 
now let's suppose that my helloworld.js code is a simple command which creates a folder on desktop. how do I execute this code ??
because my service app starts successfully but it does not do anything at all. it creates no directories on desktop.
please help.. 
what error am I doing?

Comment: How shall anybody reproduce and solve this problem if you don't provide any code or detailed instructions?

Comment: I am just asking for guidance... like tell me the simplest possible code which I can execute as window service using node-windows.. and i must be able to see its output as a window service..